# Place view in the bottom right, hiding part, programmatically swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to move the view as shown in the image programmatically, to obtain an effect similar to 1/4 of roulette.

[image]

But I only get it to show below as indicated in the code for one screen.

```
    let X_Position:CGFloat? = 150.0 //use your X position here
    let Y_Position:CGFloat? = 300.0 //use your Y position here
    circle.frame = CGRect(x: X_Position ?? 0,y: Y_Position ?? 0,width: 
    circle.frame.width,height: circle.frame.height)
```

How can I get this position for all screens?

Comment: what is the result?did you check what coordinates is lower right corner?

Comment: Edit the question to answer you. Thank you!!

Comment: you should set center = UIScreen.main.bounds.height and view.bounds.width

Comment: @ja12 - not clear what you're asking... Is the "wheel" starting in the center, and you want to animate it to the lower-right to show only 1/4 of it?

Comment: @DonMag Yes that is exactly what I am looking for, the accepted answer fits my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 4**

Without Animation:

```
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
let circleViewRect = circlemenu.frame

circlemenu.frame = CGRect.init(x: screen.width - circleViewRect.width/2, y: screen.height - circleViewRect.height/2, width: circleViewRect.width, height: circleViewRect.height)
```

With Animation:

```
let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
let circleViewRect = circlemenu.frame

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    circlemenu.frame = CGRect.init(x: screen.width - circleViewRect.width/2, y: screen.height - circleViewRect.height/2, width: circleViewRect.width, height: circleViewRect.height)
}
```

I believe you are using an old version of swift, so feel free to change the functions accordingly